# Best way to let users upload and share files from site?

Tags: php, html, web, file-sharing

I'm creating a website with PHP and MySql on the backend. The site will allow users to send files to other users. Is there any api or way to allow the users to upload files from my site and send it to other users without leaving my site? And preferably a way were I don't need to handle the servers.

I know that it's possible to upload files with PHP but I would prefer a better way :)

Comment: Go for Google..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DropBox API for PHP. Let user upload the file on DropBox and return a link of uploaded file.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/php